# Is Apache Cassandra not a good choice for aggregations?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, nosql-aggregation, column-family

I read that cassandra would not provide sufficient possibilities for aggregations like SUM or AVG.

Actually I thought the column oriented model would be the most appropriate for these kind of operations.

I read many articles, but I am just not getting it.
Besides the scalibility factor, what are then the best typical use cases for using cassandra?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra use cases:

- real time tracking and analytics workload
- time series based applications
- messaging
- IoT applications
- product catalogs, retails applications, recommendation engines.